# Nginx put another website in front

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have a wordpress website served by nginx:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name my_wordpress.example.com;
  root /var/www/wordpress;
  index index.php;
  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include fastcgi_params; 
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_url;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
  } 
}
```

What I want to do is to put one simple website consisting of only one file, let's say `index.php` to temporarily take over the root url of my domain, while keeping the access to the wordpress website on another url.

What is the best way to achieve this?

I went into the direction of setting a variable when user access the url aiming to the **wordpress** website:

```
location /original-site {
  set $request_url $request_uri;
  set $original_site "true"; 
  rewrite ^/original-site$ /; }

if ($original_site = "true") {
  set $request_url /; }
```

redirecting the root url somewhere else:

```
if ($original_site != "true") {
  rewrite ^/$ /new_website redirect; }
```

I'm using the `$request_url` in php:

```
fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_url;
```

I have not been very successful so far, I might find the bugs and finetune this approach, does there exist some more elegant way, how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure you want to only serve a simple index file when the root of your website is accessed, why don't you add just a `location = /` for that? Without any variables, `rewrite` or `if` (remember [it's better to look for a solution without `if`](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)).

The whole server part could look like:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name my_wordpress.example.com;
  root /var/www/wordpress;
  index index.php;

  location = / {
      # I'd add an expires 10s; or whatever
      return 302 original-site;
  }

  location = /original-site {
    root /var/www/a_special_other_path; # where you stored the special index file to temporarily serve
    try_files index.php index.html;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include fastcgi_params; 
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_url;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
  } 
}
```

This way, if someone tries to access exactly my_wordpress.example.com, he/she will get the index file from the special directory. But all others accesses (to my_wordpress.example.com/anything.php) will be treated by the other location block.

If you wish to temporarily serve more than a simple index.html (e.g.), you can use the same parameters in the `location = /` block as in your `location ~ \.php$` block.

And once you're done, just comment out the `location = /` block you're back to the initial configuration.

Comment: yes, that's probably part of the solution, my question is how do I serve the original root '/' renamed to let's say '/original-site' - I'd like to send it to php-fpm with request_url - '/' so I need it set in the nginx from otherwise it would serve the new site '/'

Comment: Hum, not sure to understand exactly what you want. I edited my answer to let the accesses to root (e.g. my_wordpress.example.com/) to my_wordpress.example.com/original-site; but you seem to want to redirect my_wordpress.example.com/$uri to my_wordpress.example.com/original-site/$uri, don't you? (then my needs to be adapted again: you put the fastcgi stuff in the `location = /original-site` block ). I don't understand how you intend to access your website then (what url for the admin?) (certainly you could map something depending on your IP).